# How do I use sql-password-wallet with sql-connect/sql-postgres in emacs?

Tags: postgresql, emacs, dot-emacs

I'd like to make use of **Emacs'** **sql-password-wallet** variable (defined in the **sql** library) to decrypt my **postgres** connection credentials from my GPG encrypted **auth-source**.

The **sql** library seems to define the variable **sql-password-wallet** specifically for this but I just cannot figure out how to make use of it.

I'm a newcomer to **elisp**. I'm using **Emacs** 29.1.

I have the following in my **init.el** file:

```lisp
(setq sql-postgres-options (quote ("--set" "sslmode=required" "-P" "pager=off")))
; Remove all default login parameters
(setq sql-postgres-login-params nil)
(setq sql-password-wallet '("/home/someone/.emacs.bedrock/sql-wallet.gpg"))

(setq sql-connection-alist
      '(
        (bigdb (sql-product 'postgres)
                   (sql-database (concat "postgresql://"
                                         "dbuser_ro"  ;; replace with your username
                                         "@db.example.com"
                                         ":6537"      ;; replace with your port
                                         "/bigdata"    ;; replace with your database
                                         )))))
```

When I invoke **sql-connect**, it still prompts me for the database password for the user **dbuser_ro** and, if I  provide it, the connection works.

However, I want **sql-connect** to prompt me (when needed) for my GPG passphrase instead and not the database password. It should then find the appropriate **auth-source** in my **sql-password-wallet** file and use that as my **postgres** connection credentials.

By the way, I can visit my GPG encrypted **sql-password-wallet** file and **emacs**, through the **auth-source** library, decrypts it for me and asks for the GPG passphrase as required.

Any idea on how I can get **sql-connect** to make use of **sql-password-wallet** mechanism when connecting to a **postgres** database?

**Update:** I managed to get **org-mode**'s babel `ob-sql` to work by using the following elisp to look up the auth-source.

```lisp
(defun dug/lookup-password (&rest keys)
   (when-let ((result (apply #'auth-source-search keys)))
     (funcall (plist-get (car result) :secret))))
```

I added the following to an **org-mode** document and was able to query the database with **emacs** caching my gpg passphrase.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine postgres :dbhost db.example.com :dbport 6537 :dbuser dbuser_ro :dbpassword (dug/lookup-password :max 1 :login "dbuser" :port 6537 :require '(:login :secret) :create t) :database bigdata
```

Flushed with success I tried to add this to my `sql-connection-alist` like so:

```lisp
(setq sql-postgres-login-params nil)
(setq sql-connection-alist
      '(
        (bigdb (sql-product 'postgres)
               (sql-password (dug/lookup-password :max 1 :login "dbuser_ro" :port 6537 :require '(:login :secret) :create t))
               (sql-database (concat "postgresql://"
                                     "dbuser_ro"  ;; replace with your username
                                     "@db.example.com"
                                     ":6537"      ;; replace with your port
                                     "/bigdata"    ;; replace with your database
                                         )))))
```

I get prompted for my `auth-sources` passphrase but, unfortunately, I still get prompted by `sql-interactive-mode` for the database passphrase.

I realise this is moving away from my goal of getting the **sql-password-wallet** mechanism to work.

@phils thanks for the tip about `auth-source-debug`! I do see the new function decrypting my **.authinfo.gpg** but there's never been any mention of decrypting my `sql-wallet.gpg`.

Comment: Try enabling `auth-source-debug` and checking the messages to (hopefully) see what's actually happening.

Comment: Experimentally, there's a bug in the docs: "The DATABASE and SERVER are concatenated with a slash between them" should read "The SERVER and DATABASE are concatenated with a slash between them" because that's the necessary sequence: `SERVER/DATABASE`.  If that's the issue then save that edit to your wallet file, `M-x auth-source-forget-all-cached`, and try again.  I get a result from `(funcall sql-password-search-wallet-function ...)` with that.

Comment: @phils yes, calling `(funcall sql-password-search-wallet-function ...)` works for me too but how do I incorporate it into the `sql-connection-alist`. There doesn't seem to be a way to pass the decoded credentials to `psql`.

Comment: I assume that's supposed to be automatic :/  I've not used this feature, so I can't comment from experience.  If you're getting the correct password value from that function call, though, at least you know *that* part is working correctly.